# How to add linux invisible character in C# for Hive usage?

Tags: c#, linux, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to write a small xlsx to csv (character separated value) program in C# (because windows users).

I want to be like a comma separated value, but instead of a comma, each cell is separated with the invisible character since that is the default character in hive ('\001' I believe).

how can I write this character to a file in C#?
I've tried "\001" , @"\001", "\uFEFF" but no sucess .. any pointers?

here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace excel2csv
{

    class ExcelConverter
    {

        static void openExcel(string path,String outpath,String delim)
        {
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

            foreach(Excel.Worksheet worksheet in excelWorkbook.Worksheets){
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outpath+worksheet.Name+".csv", true);
                Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
                int nRows = usedRange.Rows.Count;
                int nCols = usedRange.Columns.Count;
                for (int iRow = 1; iRow <= nRows; iRow++)
                {
                    String line = "";
                    for (int iCount = 1; iCount <= nCols; iCount++)
                    {
                        usedRange= (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[iRow, iCount];
                        line += usedRange.Text + delim;
                       // Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(worksheet.Name);
                file.Close();

            }
            Console.Read();
            excelWorkbook.Close();

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String path = @"C:\file.xlsx";
            String outpath = @"file";
            String delim = @"\001";
            openExcel(path,outpath, delim);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, the answer is below:

```
string delim = "\x01";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
            String str = @"\001";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepath, str);
```

Comment: That just writes the string "\001" instead of the invisible character .. :/

Comment: @user1745713: Okay. Could you please share the code so that it helps us to resolve the issue.